# How do I fix the npm WARN deprecated error when I install VueJS CLI

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to install VueJS CLI on my Windows 10 machine but ran into the errors below:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
```

Here's my PC setup:

```
Windows 10
Node: v12.18.2
Npm: 6.14.5
```

Comment: I think you don't have updated version of npm so `Npm install -g npm@latest` then `npm install` after doing this try to install vue.js `Npm i -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 0):

I also had many unresolved warning including `@hapi/hoek` and `@hapi/topo`. I was able to resolve all of them by running

```
npm audit fix --force
```

And of course I do understand, that it doesn't cover the 100% of cases.

Answer (score -3):

**Installing Vue Cli**

npm install -g @vue/cli

## OR

yarn global add @vue/cli

For further detail, visit the Installation Guide [enter link description here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)

Comment: The question is about how to remove the warnings? not how to install the vue cli.

Comment: Remove it and make your own custom validation. Away from depreciated.